# C - Format input string to integer variables

Tags: c, string, parsing, int

I have a string that looks like "%i|%i".
Some examples: "52|23" , "7|3" , "98|6".

I want to parse this kind of strings to two int variables.
so "52|23" will become a variable.
int a=52 and int b=23.

These strings are saved in a .txt-file.
How can I parse them out and parse them like explained above?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `fscanf`:

```
FILE *f = fopen("file.txt", "r");
if(!f) {
    /* file open failed */
}
int a, b;
while(fscanf(f, "%i|%i", &a, &b) == 2) {
    /* do something with a and b */
}
```

Comment: Awesome . Didn't know about this method lol.
Btw, what happens if the string does not match with the pattern?